# Include array into function only if it exist and is not empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function to shuffle several arrays and return one long array:

```
function array_zip_merge() {
  $output = array();
  // The loop incrementer takes each array out of the loop as it gets emptied by array_shift().
  for ($args = func_get_args(); count($args); $args = array_filter($args)) {
    // &$arg allows array_shift() to change the original.
    foreach ($args as &$arg) {
      $output[] = array_shift($arg);
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

And Im running it like this:

```
$visirezai = array_zip_merge($tretiRezai, $ketvirtiRezai, $sphinxorezaiclean);
```

The problem is sometimes one, two or even all arrays are empty or not set at all and Im getting looping error message like this:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: sphinxorezaiclean in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 177

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 148

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 148

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 148

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 148

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 148

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 148
```

Line 177 is where `$visirezai = array_zip_merge($tretiRezai, $ketvirtiRezai, $sphinxorezaiclean);` is (I understand that sphinxorezaiclean is not set at all, but sometimes it is like this) and line 148- where function `array_zip_merge` is.

And it continues like this until I stop loading web page in browser.

My approach to solve this is something like this: first I'm checking if arrays are empty or not:

```
$ketvirtiRezai = rezultataiKeturi($q);
$tretiRezai = rezultataiTrys($q);

$ketvirtiEmpty = false;
$tretiEmpty = false;
$sphinxEmpty = false;
if (empty($ketvirtiRezai[0])) {
    $ketvirtiEmpty = true;
}

if (empty($tretiRezai[0])) {
    $tretiEmpty = true;
}
else {
    $tretiRezai = array_slice($tretiRezai, 0, 5);
}

if (isset($sphinxorezai) && !empty($sphinxorezai)) {
    $sphinxorezaiclean = array_slice($sphinxorezai, 0, 5);
}
else
{
    $sphinxEmpty = true;
}
```

And then I could do super long if elseif loop by checking true or false on every single array and setting `array_zip_merge` function accordingly.

Is there any nicer way to add/remove arrays to array_zip_merge function. For example if $ketvirtiRezai is empty, function should only include `$visirezai = array_zip_merge($tretiRezai, $sphinxorezaiclean);` if all arrays are empty then $visirezai should be set as empty and function does not run at all (well this one is easy I guess). If two arrays empty one is not, $visirezai should be set to the one that is not empty.

I'm pretty new in PHP so sorry for my messy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to use the php function `is_array`, right? In your merge function:

```
function array_zip_merge() {
  $output = array();
  // The loop incrementer takes each array out of the loop as it gets emptied by array_shift().
  for ($args = func_get_args(); count($args); $args = array_filter($args)) {
    // &$arg allows array_shift() to change the original.
    foreach ($args as $key=>&$arg) {
      // check if the argument is actually an array
      if (is_array($arg)) {
        $output[] = array_shift($arg);
      } else {
        unset($args[$key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Really nice idea, but when Im checking is_array im getting this error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /usr/share/nginx/search.php on line 147 so It just hangs on that function execution. Line 147 is where this loop starts foreach ($args as &$arg) {

Comment: @DadaB, what if you add an `!empty` check: `if (!empty($arg) && is_array($arg)) {`

Comment: Try @MER's suggestion, and also try `var_export($args);` just to see what's happening there.

Comment: As mentioned before, with @MER solution still was getting execution time error. Var_export gave me this: array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, 2 => '', )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, )array ( 0 => true, 1 => true, ) and it continues like this non stop.

Comment: I would look at the code that generates the arrays sent to the function. How many arguments are you passing?

Comment: This is how data in arrays looks when function is working fine: https://pastebin.com/u6NbTWaj and this what output I'm getting when function not working and there is no data in arrays: https://pastebin.com/ygsY5Cc7 (sometimes it might be only one empty array, but Function doesn't work then anyway)

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed your for loop! Obviously, if the arg is not an array, we still need to remove it from the $args variable or the loop will never finish (`count($args)` will never reach 0). You need to unset $args[$key]. See my edit